# Trying to find documentation on UNV-SIM7100C-EVB MINI-V1.11

Tags: gps, mbed, nucleo

As the title states, I have the UNV-SIM7100C-EVB MINI-V1.11 connected to my Nucleo-F401re board and am trying to get GPS working. Can anyone help?

EDIT: I'm looking for the one bought from here: https://www.ebay.com/itm/SIM7100C-SIM7600CE-Development-Board-4G-Module-GSM-GPRS-EDGE900-1800MHz-LTE-Band-/172837022791

Comment: If I google, you can download datasheets of 'almost' similar products that might help, like SIM7100 LTE mini PCIe data sheet (https://techship.com/download/simcom-sim7100c-lte-mini-pcie-data-sheet).

Comment: I found this device [on this website](http://simcom.ee/documents/SIM7100E/sim7100x_evb_user_guide_v1.01.pdf). Firmware isn't up to date but it should get you the appropriate guidance for hardware.

Comment: I'm going down the same rabbit hole too! I would love to talk with you more if you are interested! Have you treid the At command structure: http://simcom.ee/documents/SIM7100E/SIM7100_AT%20Command%20Manual_V1.00.pdf

Answer (score -1):

I bought an UNV-SIM7100A-EVB MINI-V1.12 module and it came with these manuals. Regards!

https://es.scribd.com/document/371936107/Unv-Sim7600c-4g-Evb-Pin-Description
https://es.scribd.com/document/371936175/Unv-Sim7600c-4g-Evb-Pin-Description
https://es.scribd.com/document/371936174/UNV-SIM7600C-4G-EVB-User-manual1-0

Comment: Thank you! I didn't get these manuals with my purchase.